# What's the best way to capture output from SQL Management Studio and paste it into an Outlook email?

Tags: sql, outlook, ssms

I'm constantly executing ad-hoc queries in SQL Management Studio and need to send the results to people via email.  This happens several times a day so I'm looking for the best way to copy the results of the query from the results window into an Outlook email body so that it can be formatted in a reader friendly manner.  I haven't come up with anything that works well for me.

When it really matters, I end up going into Excel, executing the query from within there and then attaching the resulting spreadsheet.  I'm looking for something that I can do without involving Excel if possible.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'm in Outlook 2010.  From a blank message, you can click in the body, then "Table," "Excel Spreadsheet."  That inserts an Excel-linked spreadsheet into the body of the message.

Then, from SSMS, run the query to a grid -- that's where I normally view mine.  Highlight the results, copy, then click on the first cell of the email-embedded spreadsheet, and Paste.

This at least looks halfway decent, and the recipient can right-click on the embedded spreadsheet, choose "Worksheet Option / Open" and fire it off in Excel.

Comment: This works in Outlook 2013 but it's still pretty clunky. Click in the body, then Insert -> Table -> Excel Spreadsheet.  I wish there was an option to do this from inside SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

Click `Results to Text` or `Results to file` in the `SQL Editor` toolbar.

Comment: I'm aware of these options.  I haven't found one that helps me get the results into outlook nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by SSIS package. You can execute query and send email.
**Edit:** maybe use SSRS, export results to Excel and attach to email.

Comment: But this type of complexity is what I'm trying to avoid.  I'm looking for something that I can do quickly and on an ad-hoc basis within SQL Management studio.